# Google App Script - TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 7, file "Code")

Tags: vba, google-apps-script

I'm trying to convert custom function from excel VBA to App Scrip.

```vb
Public Function Objective(sv As Variant, y As Variant, x As Variant) As Variant

    sum1 = 0
    sum2 = 0
    For i = 1 To 15
        For j = 1 To 15

            sum2 = sum2 + sv(i) * sv(j) * y(i) * y(j) * (x(i, 1) * x(j, 1) + x(i, 2) * x(j, 2) + x(i, 3) * x(j, 3))

        Next j
        sum1 = sum1 + sv(i)
    Next i

    Objective = sum1 - 0.5 * sum2

End Function
```

Here's my script as Google App Script

```
 function OBJECTIVE(sv, y, x) {
  var sum1=0;
  var sum2=0;

  for(var i=0; i<15; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<15; j++){
      sum2=sum2+sv[i]*sv[j]*y[i]*y[j]*(x[i][1]*x[j][1]+x[i][2]*x[j][2]+x[i][3]*x[j][3]);
    }
    sum1=sum1+sv[i];
  }
  objective=sum1-0.5*sum2;
}
```

But I get the error on this line `sum2=sum2+sv[i]*sv[j]*y[i]*y[j]*(x[i][1]*x[j][1]+x[i][2]*x[j][2]+x[i][3]*x[j][3]);` saying `TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 7, file "Code")`. I don't see any issues with the syntax, what can be the cause?

Comment: For example, if the length of array you are using is 15, how about modifying from ``i<=15`` and ``j<=15`` to ``i<15`` and ``j<15``, respectively? Or if you are required to be the same to VBA, how about modifying from ``for(var i=0; i<=15; i++){`` and ``for(var j=0; j<=15; j++){`` to ``for(var i=1; i<=15; i++){`` and ``for(var j=1; j<=15; j++){``, respectively?

Comment: @Tanaike Right, I forgot that indexes in VBA begin at 1. I've done, as you suggested. But I don't really see the purpose of this.

Comment: @Cooper I'm doing linear SVM, unfortunately can't use python on exam, so the prof is having us do this in excel. sv - support vector (alpha), y -class, x - data matrix.

Comment: Dynamic array indices don't start at 1 in VBA unless you have `Option Base 1` specified. But this isn't Excel, and not VBA either. So why the VBA tag, and why the jab at VBA's indexing?

Comment: @Cooper sv - f1:f16, x - a1:c10, y - d2:d16. sv is blank currently,it's required for the solver. Here's my [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LCsoa3n_c550GFwfooFOOqhbg8i2P8591thKsdgwyrs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm not trying to jab anything, I'm unfamiliar with VBA, as this my first time using it.

Comment: Fair enough, but how are `sv`, `x`, and `y` populated? What is the code calling this procedure? All we know from the code is that they're `Variant` - they're 2D arrays coming from a worksheet? Is this a UDF invoked from a worksheet formula? If that's the case then intaking `Range` parameters would greatly enhance the readability. If it's used as a UDF, please show us example uses; if not, please show us the code that's invoking it and how the arrays are populated.

Comment: The hard-coded 1/15 boundaries (in either language) are begging for out-of-bounds errors. Use `LBound` and `UBound` to get the lower/upper bounds of an array. Also 0 to 15 is 16 iterations; the VBA code is making 15 iterations.

Comment: @Cooper I've adjusted the for loop ranges.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes, the `sv, x, y` are populated from the worksheet, when I call the function. E.g, `=OBJECTIVE(F2:F16, D2:D16, A2:C16)`

Comment: @Cooper Just did.

Comment: @Cooper `sv` and `y` are 1D arrays, and `x` is 3x15 matrix.

Comment: In google apps script they are two dimensional arrays.  You can read the documentation and see that they are described as Object[][]. The first element in a column array is [0][0] and the second element is [1][0] and so on.

Comment: The VBA code can't get you a 1D array through a `Variant` given it's invoked by a worksheet formula. The `Variant` argument would be a `Variant/Range` object reference, which gives you a 2D variant array through let-coercion, but the VBA code never let-coerces the ranges into a local variant array... so VBA needs query the object for an indexer, finds it... what you're getting with `sv(i)` is a `Range` object reference, because what you implicitly invoked was the `Range.[_Default]([Row],[Column])` property. The VBA code isn't working with arrays at all: it's all hidden `Range` member calls.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer to your question but I think it will help you to understand the Apps Script arrays well enough so that you can figure out the rest.  Just copy it change the sheet name as needed.  It will identify the three ranges and put their indices in each cell.

```
function playingWithArrays(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
  sh.clear();
  var rg1=sh.getRange('A2:C16');
  rg1.setBackground('lightyellow');  
  var rg2=sh.getRange('D2:D16');
  rg2.setBackground('lightblue');
  var rg3=sh.getRange('F2:F16');
  rg3.setBackground('lightgreen');
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var vB=rg2.getValues();
  var vC=rg3.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<rg1.getWidth();j++){
      vA[i][j]=Utilities.formatString('[%s][%s]',i,j);
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<vB.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<rg2.getWidth();j++){
      vB[i][j]=Utilities.formatString('[%s][%s]',i,j);
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<vC.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<rg2.getWidth();j++){
      vC[i][j]=Utilities.formatString('[%s][%s]',i,j);
    }
  } 
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(rg1.getA1Notation());
  rg1.setValues(vA);
  sh.getRange('D1').setValue(rg2.getA1Notation());
  rg2.setValues(vB);
  sh.getRange('F1').setValue(rg3.getA1Notation());
  rg3.setValues(vC);
}
```

Don't forget that a cell function must return a value. Like `return sum;`

Comment: Thank you, I'll give me a try.